# How to generate xcode project using qmake with QT

Tags: xcode, qt, qmake

using

```
qmake -spec macx-xcode
```

can only generate older version test.pbproj and can not open in xcode 4

How to generate test.xcodeproj

Comment: why someone don't know what i said, but Smith told me the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, but if you go [here to the bug reports](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-17247?focusedCommentId=150242&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel) you'll find some notes on what people did to fix it.

Comment: I believe this is the new link: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17247

Comment: The link is dead again, the new one is https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-17247